# Angular2 rc3: Error when injecting services in constructor (Cannot resolve parameters' types)

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-di

I have this constructor in my AuthGuard class:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(
        private ribbonService: RibbonService,
        private checkSessionService: CheckSessionService,
        private router: Router) { }

    // etc
}
```

When I build it is fine but I get the following error when accessing through the browser:

```
reflective_provider.js:233 Uncaught Cannot resolve all parameters for 'AuthGuard'(undefined, CheckSessionService, Router). 
Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'AuthGuard' is decorated with Injectable.
```

I don't understand why it happens only to the first service and not to the second. I thought it was a problem from inheritance cause the first service is extending BaseService but then i also made the second service extend BaseService and it works, the problematic one is only the first one....

Note I've also tried adding the @Inject decorator for each param but the result it's the same.

Thanks before hand!!

Comment: Please add the code to your question that shows how you provide `RibbonService`, `CheckSessionService`, `Router`, `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`, and all the dependencies these classes have.

Answer (score 0):

`RibbonService` (or one of its dependencies) is not imported or provided correctly.